# Proof-verification exercise problem

Tags: calculus, induction, recursion

Let $a_1=2$, $a_2=4$, and define for $n > 2$, $n$ a natural number:

> $$a_n=\:a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$$

How to prove that $a_n\:\ge \:2^n$ is always true?

When n = 3

> $$a_3=a_{3-1}+2a_{3-2}\:=a_2\:+2a_1=4\:+2\cdot 2=8$$
>   $$2^3=8$$

when n +1

> $$a_{n+1}=a_{n+1-1}+2a_{n+1-2}=a_n+2a_{n-1}$$
>   $$2^{n+1}$$

Comment: How can we verify your proof if you don't show us what it is?

Comment: try an induction on n

Comment: I tried induction, but somehow i wasn't able to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  So you are aware, this is not a homework site.  People don't usually respond to questions that show no efforts.  You describe this as "proof-verification" which would suggest that you have some proof that you'd like us to review.  Glad to do it!  Just write out what you've got and I, or others, will certainly look it over.

Comment: At a minimum, you have surely checked this numerically for modest $n$.  If you did that, you probably noticed a pattern...no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $a \ge 0$:

Start of indudction: n = 3

$$a_3 = a_2 + 2a_1 = 4 + 2*2 = 8 \ge 2^3$$

Thus

$$a_n \ge 2^n$$

for an $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Induction Step: $n \rightarrow n+1$

$$a_{n+1}=a_n + 2a_{n-1}$$

Since
$$a_n \ge 2^n$$

$$\Rightarrow a_n + 2a_{n-1}\ge 2^n $$

Comment: How do you get the last line? :) I don't really get it.

Comment: @Mari You are right, I messed something up and now I'm trying to get the solution as well, but nothing is quiet working.

Comment: @Mari When rearranging you always simply proof that the term is bigger than 2^{n-k} , k \ge 0, so there has to be a logical step to proof that it's also bigger than 2^{n+1}, but I can't point my finger to it.

Answer (score 0):

The associate caracteristic equation is

$x^2-x-2=0$ which has $x=-1$ and $x=2$ as solutions.

thus

$u_n=a(-1)^n+b(2)^n$.

with

$-a+2b=u_1=2$ and
$a+4b=u_2=4$

so
$b=1$ and $a=0$.

thus, we get

$u_n\color{red}{=}2^n$ for each integer $ n$.